# PHPUnit fails on Travis-CI but passes locally

Tags: php, phpunit, travis-ci

I'm having some trouble getting PHPUnit to work on Travis-CI when it works fine on my local machine. I'm using the same PHP version and PHPUnit version.

My codebase is at https://github.com/lncd/OAuth2
Travis-CI output is at https://travis-ci.org/lncd/OAuth2

Executing `phpunit -c build/phpunit.xml` from the root of the repository works fine locally and tests execute as expected.

The log for Travis is:

```
$ cd ~/builds
$ git clone --branch=develop --depth=100 --quiet git://github.com/lncd/OAuth2.git lncd/OAuth2
$ cd lncd/OAuth2
$ git checkout -qf 1c3b319aa6c8f5521d5123f0e6affca94ee35010
$ phpenv global 5.3
$ php --version
PHP 5.3.19 (cli) (built: Dec 20 2012 09:57:38) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2012 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by Derick Rethans
$ phpunit -c build/phpunit.xml
PHP Warning:  require_once(src/OAuth2/Authentication/Server.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/travis/builds/lncd/OAuth2/tests/authentication/server_test.php on line 3
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.3.19/bin/phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.3.19/bin/phpunit:46
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() /home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.3.19/share/pyrus/.pear/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:129
PHP   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->handleArguments() /home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.3.19/share/pyrus/.pear/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:138
PHP   5. PHPUnit_Util_Configuration->getTestSuiteConfiguration() /home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.3.19/share/pyrus/.pear/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:657
PHP   6. PHPUnit_Util_Configuration->getTestSuite() /home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.3.19/share/pyrus/.pear/php/PHPUnit/Util/Configuration.php:784
PHP   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->addTestFiles() /home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.3.19/share/pyrus/.pear/php/PHPUnit/Util/Configuration.php:860
PHP   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->addTestFile() /home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.3.19/share/pyrus/.pear/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:416
PHP   9. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::checkAndLoad() /home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.3.19/share/pyrus/.pear/php/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:355
PHP  10. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::load() /home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.3.19/share/pyrus/.pear/php/PHPUnit/Util/Fileloader.php:76
PHP  11. include_once() /home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.3.19/share/pyrus/.pear/php/PHPUnit/Util/Fileloader.php:92
```

I've played around with altering the `require_once` to load`require_once '../../src/OAuth2/Authentication/Server.php';` (i.e. two directories down from the executing file) but that doesn't work on Travis or my local setup.

What am I doing wrong? Or is it a bug with Travis?

Thank you

---

**EDIT:**

To clarify this is the directory structure:

```
build
    /phpunit.xml
src
    /OAuth2
        /Authentication
            /Database.php
            /Server.php
        /Resource
            /Database.php
            /Server.php
tests
    /authentication
        /database_mock.php
        /server_test.php
    /resource
        /database_mock.php
        /server_test.php
```

Both files called `server_test.php` under directories in /tests are trying to load respective `Server.php` and `Database.php` files from directories under /src

Comment: `var_dump(getcwd(), get_include_path());`

Comment: `getcwd`: /home/travis/builds/lncd/OAuth2  

`include path`: .:/home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.3.19/pear:/home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.3.19/share/pyrus/.pear/php  

`__FILE__`: /home/travis/builds/lncd/OAuth2/tests/authentication/server_test.php  

`__DIR__`: /home/travis/builds/lncd/OAuth2/tests/authentication

Comment: It looks like you are not installed all requirements.

Comment: Although this was written with ruby in mind, it is applicable for php: http://ruby-journal.com/debug-your-failed-test-in-travis-ci/

Comment: @IgorTimoshenko I've just noticed I wasn't running `composer install` so I've added that to the `.travis.yml` file, regardless none of the tests rely on code from that - latest build still failed https://travis-ci.org/lncd/OAuth2/builds/3923096

Comment: Where you get OAuth classes? Is it classes from some independent library? If yes, are you describe this library in composer.json?

Comment: @IgorTimoshenko see my update to the question - the files that are trying to be loaded are under /src

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I saw from your repository, you are required files using by related link from the current directory. So, PHPUnit tries to find required files in the same directory where you put tests and does not find any files. You need to change usage of `require_once` to `../../src/OAuth2/Resource/Server.php` or add bootstrap.php file for PHPUnit.

Below I copy-pasted my bootstrap.php file that I use with PHPUnit and Composer:

```
<?php
if (!@include __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php') {
    die('You must set up the project dependencies, run the following commands:
        wget http://getcomposer.org/composer.phar
        php composer.phar install');
}
```

More information about bootstrap.php file you can find here: http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html.

Comment: I've tried that already - https://travis-ci.org/lncd/OAuth2/jobs/3922238 - still broken on Travis and now broken locally

Comment: Try to add bootstrap.php file. Using `require` in tests is not a good approach.

Comment: Thank you, I misunderstood what you were proposing. It's working now.